# remove white overlay

Tags: css

I am trying to find a way to remove the white overlay on my pages in the website  my event or artist. I tried to use inspect element to locate  what created the white overlay but i was unable to locate the exact property.

pages: http://rightwayent.net/tc-events/words-unleashed-respect-the-artist/

http://rightwayent.net/album/dane-ray/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On both pages template find `<div class="overlay-for-image-bg">` and replace it with `<div>` only. Needles to say, you should make this change in child theme's template, to avoid your changes being overwritten when you update your theme.

Or you can modify `/wp-content/uploads/mesh/custom.css` file by removing the following block:

```
.overlay-for-image-bg {
    /* some stuff */
}
```

Comment: Thank you it worked, thank you for the recommendation about the child theme.